# iOS how to debug a crash?

Tags: ios

My app crash for an indefined reason and I end up with this log:

MyProj[9442:707] -[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e6690

Can I have any more details ? What does 9442:707 mean, is it a line number ?

**EDIT**

In my code, I have added traces like:

```
NSLog(@"KEYS:%@", myKeys);
NSLog(@"KEYS ORDERED:%@", [myKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]);
```

But the second line crashes. The "length" error I have seems to come from this line (I do not use [something length] anywhere though).

```
2011-11-11 14:20:18.936 MyProj[9570:707] KEYS:(
  330,
  359,
  362,
  367,
  352,
  351,
  364,
  331,
  350
)

... then crash... with above error
```

Comment: give this a check out : how to trace and debug a crash in iOS: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-trace-and-debug-an-ios-crash-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS debugger is rather unclear in describing the exact problem sometimes.
Yet in your case it should be clear. `[NSDecimalNumber length]` cannot be executed because the method length us unclear to it.

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Try finding the line where you use the length function and change it to something that does work. With a piece of code in your question we could be more precise on that.

Comment: I do not use "length" in the code, seems to be linked while sorting an array (I have added a part of the code in the question).

Comment: @Luc: The compare: method. Will do something under the covers with the length function. It might as well be that.

Comment: You'r right, length is called in the compare method. I have just seen that the objects compared were not all NSString, there was a NSDecimalNumber hidden among them... I changed it into a NSString and it's working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

9442:707 is information about the process .. it's not going to help you here.

Somewhere in your code you're sending the length message to an NSDecimalNumber.

Can you make the crash happen in the debugger?  If so, check the call stack at the time of the crash, and it should point you right to the problem.

If not - if your code base isn't too large you could search your code for "length" and inspect anywhere you're sending the length message to see if it could be sending it to the wrong type of object.

Comment: I managed to isolate the error but does not seems to be because of an explicit [something length] call though. I have updated the question and added additional logs.